# node.js flatiron - file uploads by multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, flatiron.js, formidable

I have a flatiron app that now needs to be expanded to handle multipart/form-data upload of images.

How does one handle file uploads in a flatiron app? union/director seem to ignore multipart/form-data, and all my attempts to integrate formidable have failed - I assume this is because of the actions union performs before formidable gets a hold of the request object.

I have tried normal and `streaming: true` routes, as well as raw handling in the `before` array.

I can't be the only person who needs this, so it's probably been addressed and I apologize. I just can't find any reference materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use union with connect.multipart (or bodyParser) which already uses node-formidable.

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    union = require('union');


var server = union.createServer({
  buffer: false,
  before: [
    connect.bodyParser(),
    function(req, res) {
                if (req.method==='POST'){
                        console.log(req.files);
                        res.end('Done');
                }else{
                        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                        res.end('<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
                                '<input type="file" name="file" />' +
                                '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />' +
                                '</form>');
                }
    },
  ]
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I ended up simply running two servers side by side inside the same node application, with one of them strictly handling uploads. That was a viable option in my case since the app sits behind a reverse proxy anyhow.

Comment: Any way to do it without connect? Isn't flatiron supposed to be a connect alternative?

Comment: Well, you could actually use what connect uses, which is node-formidable but I frankly prefer using connect. Regarding your second question.. Actually flatiron-union has been written to support external middlewares like connect's. Flatiron and connect aren't really competing, they do different things (I'd say flatiron is competing more with bigger framework like express than with connect)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to turn buffering off in the Union options, and streaming: true in your endpoint's options:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    union = require('../../lib'),
    director = require('director'),
    favicon = require('./middleware/favicon'),

    // for uploading:
    formidable = require('formidable'),
    util = require('util');

var router = new director.http.Router();

var server = union.createServer({
  buffer: false,
  before: [
    favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.png')),
    function (req, res) {
      var found = router.dispatch(req, res);
      if (!found) {
        res.emit('next');
      }
    }
  ]
});

router.get('/foo', function () {
  this.res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  this.res.end('<form action="/foo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>');
});

router.post('/foo', { stream: true }, function () {
  var req = this.req,
      res = this.res,
      writeStream;

      var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

      console.log('Receiving file upload');

      form
        .on('field', function(field, value) {
          console.log(field, value);
        })
        .on('file', function(field, file) {
          console.log(field, file);
        })
        .on('progress', function(rec, expected) {
          console.log("progress: " + rec + " of " +expected);
        })

        .parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

          console.log('Parsed file upload' + err);

          res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
          if (err) {
            res.end('error: Upload failed: ' + err);
          }
          else {
            res.end('success: Uploaded file(s): ' + util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
          }
        });

});

server.listen(9090);
console.log('union with director running on 9090');
```